# HOw to convert jquery to react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, onblur, onfocus

I have jquery code how we can convert it to React js
I want to achieve onfocus and onblur on input to add and remove class on specific div.

Anyone have any idea how we can achieve this.

```
$("input#password").focus(function() {
  $("#overlay").addClass("newoverlay");
}).blur(function() {
  $("#overlay").removeClass("newoverlay");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay" class="">Focus/Blur</div>
<input type="txt" id="password"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

const foo: React.FC = () => {
  const [isFocused, setFocus] = React.useState(false);

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setFocus(true);
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    setFocus(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`someClass ${isFocused && 'focus'}`}
      onFocus={handleFocus}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    >
      hello
    </div>
  );
}

export default foo;
```

here is the code what you looking for.

you can check react event in following link
https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

and also using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) or clsx is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert that code into 'React' from jQuery. The simple way is just include '$' the add that code like the following method. It will work.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import $ from 'jquery';

    function ExampleFunction(props) {

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input#password").focus(function() {
         $("#overlay").addClass("newoverlay");
        }).blur(function() {
          $("#overlay").removeClass("newoverlay");
        });
      });

return (<React.Fragment>
<div> Your code </div>
</React.Fragment>);
}

export default ExampleFunction;
```

You may need to update this code based on the class-based or functional components respectively.

Comment: but i want to write the above code in react. Do you have any idea how we can write this code into react.

Comment: This is a horrible example, please do not follow this. A waste of reputation to downvote

Comment: jquery access to real dom but react uses virtual dom. combining two libraries is not good.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not needed to apply a certain class you can simply use css only with the focus selector. See here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

For example

```css
#overlay:focus {
 some-property: true;
}
```

Then import the css file in your react setup. (For example with create-react-app)